# rpc.mountd[pid]: /xxx and /yyy have same filehandle for host, using first

Tags: nfs, amazon-s3, nfs4, s3fs

I have an S3 bucket mounted using [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) at `/yyy` and a normal drive mounted at `/xxx`. I am exporting both with NFS however when a client attempts mount, I see the following error:

```
rpc.mountd[pid]: /xxx and /yyy have same filehandle for <client_hostname>, using first
```

The non s3 mount is exported using:

```
/xxx client_hostname(async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,rw)
```

and the s3 mount:

```
/yyy client_hostname(async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,ro,fsid=1,crossmnt)
```